# Multiclass text classification imbalance, dealing with class "other"

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, text-mining, text-classification, multiclass-classification

I'm looking for a way to use machine learning to correctly classify FAQs that don't fit in with pre-defined classes, and should get lumped into an "other" class.

**The problem:** in the training dataset contains about 1500 FAQs, with "other" being the largest class (about 250 questions are lumped in this class). These are typically "odd-ball" questions, that are asked very infrequently. However, when I train a model, the "other" class becomes a model favourite, just because of the size and variance compared to other classes. If I now use this model to classify the FAQs without class, a decent amount will be lumped into "other" where they shouldn't.

**What I want:** a model that classifies questions with the specific classes first, and only lumps it in "other" when it can't find a good hit with the specific classes.

**What I've tried:** undersample the "other" class. This works OKish, but I think there should be a better solution.

I'll try to use the number of times a FAQ is asked as second predictor (not sure how yet), but I'm looking for any out-of-the-box solutions or pointers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest two strategies to do this classification (however, it is better to say clusstering since it is an unsupervised learning):

**First method:** use NLP (`nltk` for example), to discover n most frequent words in the questions and consider them as the class labels. To do so, you need to create a corpus by integrating all the question, clean the text by removing punctuation, stopwords, digit, mention, hashtags and so on, then tokenise and lemmatise the text, and find the most common tokens. I believe it is better to keep only nouns, and take most common nouns. Besides, you can compute [tf–idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf), and decide based on that instead.

**Second method:** use fuzzy techniques to compute the similarities between text. To do so, you can use `fuzzywuzzy` library that contains several functions for computing the similarities. For your case `fuzzywuzzy.token_set_ratio()` would be the right choice, since you are comparing two sentences. However, since you have 1500 questions, you have `(n * (n-1)) / 2 = 1124250` combination to compute similarity for, which is a lot. To make it efficient, I suggest to use `itertools`

Hope these help!